# how to encrypt/decrypt sqs messages from KMS policy

Tags: encryption, server, amazon-sqs, amazon-kms, aws-policies

```js
{
            "Sid": "Some_ID",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "sqs.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
```

messages should be encrypted to unauthorised users and automatically decrypt in sqs for authorised user/queue.

Comment: .. and what is your question? When you enable encryption of the SQS storage, data are encrypted, the client doesn't need to do anything.

Comment: @gusto2:- I enabled SSE on SQS, i do not see messages in encrypted form , i just see plain JSON text. How can i see encrypted messages in messageBody?

Comment: nope, the encryption is completely transparent for the client.

Comment: @gusto2:- thanks for the reply, but if there is no difference in messageBody sent between encrypted and unencrypted text then what is the functionality of SQS encryption using KMS key?

Comment: the difference is the data in the underlying storage will  be encrypted, but the client itself won't see that. Plus there are  charges for SQS calling KMS and quota limits of KMS
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-server-side-encryption.html#sqs-encryption-what-does-sse-encrypt

Comment: gusto2:- thank you, underlying storage do you mean aws servers? so you are saying the user who has created the queue/ the recipient won't be able to see the message body which is encrypted and there will be no difference in message body even after enabling encryption? then is there a way to confirm messages are getting encrypted? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-sse-existing-queue.html I enabled encryption manually using these steps.

Comment: exactly. SQS encrypts the messages under the hood, but the client doesn't see any change. You can see the encryption only by the ckeckbox in a console and extra lines on your invoice.  (I'm not sure if sqs calls to kms are logged in the cloudtrail, I believe not)

Comment: @gusto2:- thank you so much for the clarification, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gusto2:- the difference is the data in the underlying storage will be encrypted, but the client itself won't see that.